# How do I SCP/FTP to a Coraid SR2421

Tags: storage

I need to save data to a Coraid SR2421.

I am no expert and I'm trying to understand how this costy piece of hardware works.

All I have is a Ethernet cable connecting my laptop and the coraid to a switch and the coraid's console with cursor blinking.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

edit and further explanation:

I've tried using software on the coraid website but It's not working.
So I've contacted the support and they sent me a file to upload on the coraid.

It looks like if I upgrade coraid's firmware then I'll be able to use the coraid software on the windows side.
That's why I'd need SCP/FTP or any kind of solution to copy a file in the partition that can be read from coraid console command line so I can launch the update command as requested.

I hope I was a bit clearer now.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I simply want to mount it on windows... It should be already configured but I can't see it from my computer.

Comment: You really shouldn't change fundamental parts of the question once a answer has been given. Your original question: "How do I SCP/FTP to a Coraid SR2421" yields a completely different response. One of: "You can't". You should ask your new question after accepting the appropriate one. Your new question would give us details about your journey including that you've discovered you can't SCP to it. Quite frankly, I'm not sure why you're sitting in front of > $10K machine without knowing what it is.

Comment: It is part of old equipment we've had at the office: I'm trying to figure out if I can simply format it and use it or if we have to dismiss it.
If knew how it worked I'd have never written here, at least not in such a confusing way :)

Comment: Re-corrected the answer...
I hope now we can proceed with no harm :)

Comment: Have you read the manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coraid SR2421 is an ATA-over-Ethernet SAN device. You will need an ATAoE client. 
As it's a layer 2 device you should be able to just plug it in directly into your laptop using a cross over cable.

You will also need to ensure that the disks are exposed and MAC address security restrictions are not in place through the console.

Comment: I've tried the ATAoE client (free) from solarwinds but still I can't mount my coraid and save data on it...

Comment: You have given no information as to why you can't mount it or save data to it.

Comment: Because I don't have information...

What should I do?

If I try SolarWinds AoE Initiator I slect the right disk and then it says:
The following virtual device was installed:
No device description.

Comment: "An error occurred during installation of the device: driver failure"

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the driver and not the Coraid. Try using another AoE initiator, such as http://winaoe.org/ or use an Ubuntu box which has an AoE initiator available. Seeing as though you have access to Coraid support you may wish to look at the manual and see if it mentions SFTP support.

Comment: AoE initiator from solarwinds worked GREAT after simply checking the "force configuration" flag.
It was not rocket science, in the end :)

Thanks